# Is it possible to create a delay of less than 0.001 seconds using circuitpython?

Tags: time, sleep, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

hardware: raspberry pi pico

language: adafruit-circuitpython

TL;DR: 0.001 sec is the maximum precision that time.sleep() can perform.
how can we get over it, using circuitpython?
The 'utime' library works only on micropython...

The long story:
look at the following code:

```
import time

x = time.monotonic_ns()

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1.0005)
    print (time.monotonic_ns()-x)
```

You would expect the output to be something like

- 1000500000
- 2001000000
- 3001500000
- 4002000000
- ...

But the output is:

- 1000976563 (almost 1001000000 )
- 2000976563 (almost 2001000000 )
- 3000976563 (almost 3001000000 )
- 4000976563 (almost 4001000000 )
- 5000976563 (almost 5001000000 )

I believe somewhere along the way there is an issue of floats representation using not enough bits, because:

1,000,000,000 / 1024 = 976562.5

But I'm really new to all of this stuff so I'll be glad to get help from you all.

Comment: the difference between your expected output and your actual output is roughly the factor for seconds to nanoseconds. I would expect a number in the billions of nanoseconds for a delay of seconds. So maybe you want to update your question and get rid of that factor to point out the real difference between expected and actual seen?

Comment: Not sure I understand your suggestion.
Do you suggest that I'll edit the post such that the output would be 1, 2, 3 ect.?

Comment: _I_ would have expected `time.monotonic_ns()-x` to give back values like `1000500000`, `2001000000` and so on... 1 s = 1000 ms, 1 ms = 1000 μs, 1 μs = 1000 ns, so 1s = 1000000000 ns.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/time.html
Micropython has multiple sleep functions (sleep, sleep_ms, and sleep_us)
providing more accurate timings. See if they exist in your library.

It also says that Floating point times may be accepted only on some boards.

https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/time/
This site says circuit python has a different set of time functions

time.monotonic_ns(), supervisor.ticks_ms(), and time.monotonic_ns()
availability of these function also depends on the board.